# JSP cannot find css and images

Tags: css, jsp

So, I have the classical problem described in the post title. In my jsp, I am trying to look for the css using this:

@import url(WebContent/css/adminstyle.css);

In order to help me diagnose the problem, I am trying to print on the jsp itself the value of what the above statement is resolving the url to. How can I get it
to print the value of:

@import url(WebContent/css/adminstyle.css)

I want to know what url the above statement in resulting in after it is evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using above statement to include css? You can use javascript statement to do your task.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Here i have style.css in **css** folder.
and even if you can find your images, you can find path to it or any file in project using,

```
String absolutePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("image.jpeg");
```

**absolutePath** can be used in img tag. Just put it in scriptlet.